# higher order derivatives of three composite functions

Tags: functions, derivatives

How can I obtain a formula for higher order derivatives for composite of three functions as $f(g(h(x)))$?

Comment: Just keep using the chain rule over and over, very carefully... (you will also need the product rule).

Comment: Check out Faá di Bruno's [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to get a formula for $n^{th}$ order derivative of $f(g(h(x)))$.How can I get it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a two step approach based upon the $n$-th derivative of the composite of two functions. It is stated as identity (3.56) in H.W. Gould's *[Tables of Combinatorial Identities, Vol. I](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.1.PDF)* and called:

> **Hoppe Form of Generalized Chain Rule**
>
> Let $D_g$ represent differentiation with respect to $g$ and $g=g(x)$. Hence $D^n_x f(g)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.  The following is valid for $n\geq 1$:
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^n f(g)=\sum_{k=1}^nD_g^kf(g)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}g^{k-j}D_x^ng^j\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

If we consider $g=g(h)$ and $h=h(x)$, we can apply Hoppes formula *twice* in order to find the $n$-th derivative of $f(g(h(x)))$:

> The following is valid for $n\geq 1$:
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^n f(g(h))&=\sum_{k=1}^nD_g^kf(g(h))\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\left(g(h)\right)^{k-j}
> D_x^n\left(g(h)\right)^j\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^nD_g^kf(g(h))\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\left(g(h)\right)^{k-j}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\sum_{p=1}^nD_h^p\left(g(h)\right)^j\frac{(-1)^p}{p!}\sum_{q=1}^p(-1)^q\binom{p}{q}h^{p-q}D_x^nh^q\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

**Example $n=1,2$**

In order to see formula (2) in action we evaluate it for small $n=1,2$. Since we need for the evaluation of (2) the $n$-th derivative of the composite of two functions we start with (1) for $n=1,2$. To ease  reading we often omit the argument $x$. We write e.g.
\begin{align*}
f^\prime(g)\cdot g^\prime\qquad\text{instead of}\qquad f^\prime(g(x))\cdot g^\prime(x)
\end{align*}
We also use *[Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* to enhance readability.

> **$D_x^1 f(g)$:**
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^1 f(g)&=\sum_{k=1}^1D_g^kf(g)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}g^{j}D_x^1g^j\\
> &=D_g^1f(g)\frac{(-1)^1}{1!}\left((-1)^1\binom{1}{1}g^0D_xg^1\right)\\
> &=f^\prime(g)\cdot g^\prime
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **$D_x^2 f(g)$:**
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^2 f(g)&=\sum_{k=1}^2D_g^kf(g)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}g^{k-j}D_x^2g^j\\
> &=[k=1]D_g f(g)\frac{(-1)^1}{1!}\left((-1)\binom{1}{1}g^0D_x^2g\right)\\
> &\qquad+[k=2]D_g^2f(g)\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)\binom{2}{1}g^1D_x^2g+\binom{2}{2}g^0D_x^2g^2\right)\\
> &=f^\prime(g)\cdot g^{\prime\prime}+f^{\prime\prime}(g)\frac{1}{2}\left(-2gg^{\prime\prime}+D_x\left(2gg^\prime\right)\right)\\
> &=f^\prime(g)\cdot g^{\prime\prime}+f^{\prime\prime}(g)\frac{1}{2}
> \left(-2gg^{\prime\prime}+2{g^{\prime}}^2+2gg^{\prime\prime}\right)\\
> &=f^\prime(g)\cdot g^{\prime\prime}+f^{\prime\prime}(g)\cdot {g^{\prime}}^2\\
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **$D_x^1 f(g(h))$:**
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^1 f(g(h))&=\sum_{k=1}^1D_g^kf(g(h))\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\left(g(h)\right)^{k-j}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\sum_{p=1}^1D_h^p\left(g(h)\right)^j\frac{(-1)^p}{p!}\sum_{q=1}^p(-1)^q\binom{p}{q}h^{p-q}D_x^1h^q\\
> &=D_gf(g(h))\cdot(-1)\left((-1)\binom{1}{1}\left(D_h^1\left(g(h)\right)^1\cdot(-1)\left((-1)\binom{1}{1}h^0D_x^1h\right)\right)\right)\\
> &=D_g(f(g(h))\cdot D_h(g(h))\cdot D_x(h)\\
> &=f^{\prime}(g(h))\cdot g^{\prime}(h)\cdot h^{\prime}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **$D_x^2 f(g(h))$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^2 f(g(h))&=\sum_{k=1}^2D_g^kf(g(h))\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\left(g(h)\right)^{k-j}\\
> &\qquad\cdot\sum_{p=1}^2D_h^p\left(g(h)\right)^j\frac{(-1)^p}{p!}\sum_{q=1}^p(-1)^q\binom{p}{q}h^{p-q}D_x^2h^q\\
> &=[k=1]D_gf(g(h))\cdot(-1)\left((-1)\binom{1}{1}\left(g(h)\right)^0\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\left([p=1]D_h(g(h))^1\cdot(-1)\left((-1)\binom{1}{1}h^0D_x^2h^1\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+[p=2]D_h^2\left(g(h)\right)^1\frac{1}{2}\left.\left.\left((-1)\binom{2}{1}h^1D_x^2h^1
> +\binom{2}{2}h^0D_x^2h^2\right)\right)\right)\\
> &\quad+[k=2]D_g^2f(g(h))\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left([j=1](-1)\binom{2}{1}\left(g(h)\right)^1\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\left([p=1]D_h^1\left(g(h\right)^1\cdot(-1)\left((-1)\binom{1}{1}h^0D_x^2h^1\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\left.[p=2]D_h^2\left(g(h)\right)^1\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)\binom{2}{1}h^1D_x^2h^1+\binom{2}{2}h^0D_x^2h^2\right)\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+[j=2]\binom{2}{2}\left(g(h)\right)^0\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\left([p=1]D_h^1\left(g(h)\right)^2\cdot(-1)\left((-1)\binom{1}{1}h^0D_x^2h^1\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\left.\left.[p=2]D_h^2\left(g(h)\right)^2\frac{1}{2}\left((-1)\binom{2}{1}h^1D_x^2h^1+\binom{2}{2}h^0D_x^2h^2\right)\right)\right)\\
> &=[k=1]D_gf(g(h))\left(D_h(g(h))D_x^2h
> +D_h^2\left(g(h)\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left.\left(-2hD_x^2h
> +D_x^2h^2\right)\right)\right)\\
> &\quad+[k=2]D_g^2f(g(h))\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left([j=1](-2)g(h)\left(D_h g(h)D_x^2h^1
> +D_h^2 g(h) \frac{1}{2}\left(-2hD_x^2h+D_x^2h^2\right)\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad+[j=2]\left(D_h\left(g(h)\right)^2D_x^2h\right.
> +\left.\left.D_h^2\left(g(h)\right)^2\frac{1}{2}\left(-2hD_x^2h+D_x^2h^2\right)\right)\right)\\
> \end{align*}

Since
\begin{align*}
-2hD_x^2h+D_x^2h^2&=-2hh^{\prime\prime}+D_x\left(2hh^\prime\right)\\
&=-2hh^{\prime\prime}+2{h^{\prime}}^2+2hh^{\prime\prime}\\
&=2{h^{\prime}}^2
\end{align*}

> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^2 f(g(h))&=D_gf(g(h))\left(D_h(g(h))D_x^2h
> +D_h^2\left(g(h)\right)\cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\\
> &\quad+D_g^2f(g(h))\frac{1}{2}\left((-2)g(h)\left(D_h g(h)D_x^2h
> +D_h^2 g(h) \cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left(D_h\left(g(h\right)^2D_x^2h\right.
> +\left.\left.D_h^2\left(g(h))\right)^2\cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\right)\\
> &=f^\prime(g(h))\left(g^\prime(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}
> +g^{\prime\prime}(h)\cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\\
> &\quad+f^{\prime\prime}(g(h))\frac{1}{2}\left((-2)g(h)\left(g^{\prime}(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}
> +g^{\prime\prime}(h) \cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left(2g(h)\cdot g^{\prime}(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}\right.
> +\left.\left.D_h\left(2g(h)\cdot g^{\prime}(h)\right)\cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\right)\\
> &=f^\prime(g(h))\left(g^\prime(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}
> +g^{\prime\prime}(h)\cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\\
> &\quad+f^{\prime\prime}(g(h))\frac{1}{2}\left((-2)g(h)\left(g^{\prime}(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}
> +g^{\prime\prime}(h) \cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\left(2g(h)\cdot g^{\prime}(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}\right.
> +\left.\left.2{g^{\prime}(h)}^2\cdot {h^\prime}^2+2g(h)\cdot  g^{\prime\prime}(h)\cdot {h^{\prime}}^2\right)\right)\\
> &=f^\prime(g(h))\left(g^\prime(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}
> +g^{\prime\prime}(h)\cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)+f^{\prime\prime}(g(h))\cdot{g^{\prime}(h)}^2\cdot {h^\prime}^2\\
> \end{align*}

The last step was a little bit cumbersome, but we finally managed it and got results in accordance with Wolfram Alpha.

> Here the summary
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^1 f(g)&=f^\prime(g)\cdot g^\prime\\
> D_x^2 f(g)&=f^\prime(g)\cdot g^{\prime\prime}+f^{\prime\prime}(g)\cdot {g^{\prime}}^2\\
> \\
> D_x^1 f(g(h))&=f^{\prime}(g(h))\cdot g^{\prime}(h)\cdot h^{\prime}\\
> D_x^2 f(g(h))&=f^\prime(g(h))\left(g^\prime(h)\cdot h^{\prime\prime}
> +g^{\prime\prime}(h)\cdot {h^\prime}^2\right)
> +f^{\prime\prime}(g(h))\cdot{g^{\prime}(h)}^2\cdot {h^\prime}^2
> \end{align*}