# Higher order derivatives of the conjugate of a function

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, derivatives, chain-rule

I have two smooth functions $f, \phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\phi$ is invertible with smooth inverse $\phi^{-1}$.  I want to know the $n$-th derivative of the composite function $\phi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi$.

More precisely, supposing that $f(0) = \phi(0) = \phi^{-1}(0) = 0$, I'm looking for a formula for $$(\phi^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi)^{(n)}(0)$$ in terms of just the derivatives for $f$ and $\phi$ (and $\phi^{-1}$).

For the composite of two functions, [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula) works out the combinatorics of the $n$-th derivative, but applying the formula twice gives a mess that doesn't seem to simplify much in my special case.  There is also an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364542/higher-order-derivatives-of-three-composite-functions), but it seems to have a gap, and again it doesn't use the fact that my composite is obtained by conjugating a function.